# NodeJS - NPM fails to install nodemon package

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

I've been trying to install `nodemon` using `npm install -g nodemon`, but I keep getting the following error. Please help

```
C:\Users\AllJs\Desktop\FF>npm install -g nodemon
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\nodemon\1.9.1\package.tgz
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\AllJSAdmin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "nodemon"
npm ERR! node v4.2.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.1
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\nodemon
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\nodemon'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\nodemon']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\nodemon',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\nodemon',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack:
npm ERR!    [ 'C:\\Users\\AllJSAdmin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\fstream\\lib\\dir-writer.js:35:25',
npm ERR!      'C:\\Users\\AllJSAdmin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\mkdirp\\index.js:47:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)' ] }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AllJS\Desktop\FF\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `npm config get prefix`

Comment: Try running your CMD as administrator

Comment: @JasonWihardja this will just lead to more problems in the future, he should fix this properly instead of running any npm commands as Administrator.

Comment: Here is the output of `npm config get prefix`  `C:\Users\AllJs\Desktop\FF>npm config get prefix`   
//Output
`C:\Program Files\nodejs`

Comment: my config prefix is in my c:\users\dell1\appdata\roaming\npm\ (ignore the case). Still it is not allowing me with Admin rights

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to write to `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\`. Check your npm configuration, it should not be trying to store packages there.

Run `npm config get prefix` to determine the current npm folders prefix. On my Windows machine this will return something in the form:

`C:\Users\<My Username>\AppData\Roaming\npm`

which is a user writable location.

Comment: Jonas, thanks for jumping in. Where exactly do I go about finding the npm config file you're talking about? And what am I supposed to modify in that file to make it work?

Comment: I just commented on your question